# Using jq, how to append an element to an array without it updating every other object?

Tags: arrays, json, append, jq

I have a test.json file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "array": [
      "string1",
      "string2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "object1": {
      "subobject1": {},
      "subobject2": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "object2": {}
  }
]
```

I'm trying to append an element, `string3` into `array`. I've tried the following commands:

```
$ jq '.[] | .array |= . + ["string3"]' test.json
$ jq '.[] | .array += ["string3"]' test.json
```

What I expect is this, `string3` only being appended to `array`:

```
{
  "array": [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
  ]
}
{
  "object1": {
    "subobject1": {},
    "subobject2": {}
  },
}
{
  "object2": {},
}
```

However, I get these as the actual result, where the `array` array is being added to all objects:

```
{
  "array": [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
  ]
}
{
  "object1": {
    "subobject1": {},
    "subobject2": {}
  },
  "array": [
    "string3"
  ]
}
{
  "object2": {},
  "array": [
    "string3"
  ]
}
```

How can I append to the one array `array` without affecting any other objects in the file?

I'm using jq version 1.6.

Comment: What if a key named "array" appears in multiple objects?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "linux"? Did you read the tag's description?

Answer (score 3):

Well, does something like this work for you?

```
jq '.[0].array += ["string3"]' test.json
```

I see this response, which looks pretty much like what I would want:

```
[
  {
    "array": [
      "string1",
      "string2",
      "string3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "object1": {
      "subobject1": {},
      "subobject2": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "object2": {}
  }
]
```

EDIT 1:
I like the more general solutions provided by @peak particularly the first one:

```
map( if .array then .array += ["string3"] else . end)
```

Here's a [snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/bzuuaVHtYK) you can experiment with. It's easy to see how you could insert the new string into the second contained array rather than the first with:

```
 map( if .array2 then .array2 += ["string3"] else . end)
```

Comment: It does but I'm curious: what if `array` wasn't the first object? How can we use `jq` to find some key and append there, wherever it is?

Comment: Must be possible. Not sure how to do that off the top of my head. Probably you can find something like that here on StackOverflow already.

Comment: I've been searching but no luck. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements, you may wish to consider:

```
map( if .array then .array += ["string3"] else . end)
```

or even:

```
walk( if type == "object" and .array then .array += ["string3"] else . end)
```

If you only want the first occurrence at the top-level to be affected:

```
(first(.[]|.array // empty)) += ["string3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to find object by key `array` and append there

```
jq '.[] | select(has("array")).array += ["string3"]' test.json
```

This is what the response looks like

```
{
  "array": [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
  ]
}
{
  "object1": {
    "subobject1": {},
    "subobject2": {}
  }
}
{
  "object2": {}
}
```